# H2 embedded database intellij idea <-> sources files

Tags: java, sql, database, embedded, h2

something wrong here but don't understand where, im trying to use H2 database as a local, "Embedded" database for my java project. So after generating my db, i created table and sample data with intellij database console but when i try to connect with sources files i fail my requests

Here is my intellij entry :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Qo9.png

And here my source files entry :

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Database {

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;

    public Database() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + "./ava", "root", "password");
            System.out.println("Status : connected");
            st = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I just don't how understand how i cannot have access to my datas, i have

```html
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "POSTE" non trouvée
Table "POSTE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM POSTE [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
(...)
```

when i'm trying to req "SELECT * FROM POSTE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./ava` is a relative database path. `.` means the current working directory of a process. Your IDE and your application launched from that IDE usually have different working directories.

You need to use absolute database paths (`C:\path\to\db` or `/path/to/db`) or you can use paths relative to the home directory of your user (`~/…`).

You also need to make sure that DB tool in your IDE and your application both use exactly the same version of H2, because you use embedded databases. When you use different versions of H2 with the same embedded database file, this file may be corrupted. (When you use H2 server process, you may safely connect to it using different versions of H2's drivers.)

Comment: Yes thanks working fine now, time to spring boot i guess :)